# Query optimization get rid of Order by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-execution-plan

On a SQL Server instance I have the following tables :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DIALPLAN](
    [IdDialPlan] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Prefixe] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [Type] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Country] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TMP_DIALPLAN] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IdDialPlan] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [CK_TMP_DIALPLAN_UNIQUE] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Prefixe] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CALLS](
    [uniqueid] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [accountcode] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [OutTel] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [lastapp] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [lastdata] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [CallLocalTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [answer] [datetime] NULL,
    [CallEnd] [datetime] NULL,
    [duration] [int] NULL,
    [CallDuration] [int] NULL,
    [disposition] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Destination] [text] NULL,
    [Asterisk] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Endreason] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [CLI] [varchar](80) NULL
)
```

The `DIALPLAN` table contains all phone numbers prefixes (100K rows) the field `Prefixe` contains the prefix value (for example 1403 for Canada Alberta or 33665 for France Mobile Bouygues) and the `CALLS` table contains phone calls (always selecting a batch of 1K rows). The purpose of the following queries is to find the right prefix for each phone number (field `OutTel` of the `CALLS` table). The right prefix is the longest prefix that matches the phone number :

```
-- Solution 1 4200ms : Sort 40%  Top 10%
SELECT TOP 1000 SUBSTRING(OutTel,3,LEN(OutTel)), FN.IdDialPlan, FN.Description
  FROM [dbo].[CALLS]
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 IdDialPlan, Description FROM [dbo].[DIALPLAN] dp WHERE dp.Prefixe = LEFT(SUBSTRING(OutTel,3,LEN(OutTel)),LEN(dp.Prefixe)) ORDER BY LEN(Prefixe) DESC) AS FN


-- Solution 2 3400ms : Sort(Join) 50%
SELECT TOP 1000 SUBSTRING(calls.OutTel,3,LEN(calls.OutTel)), dp.IdDialPlan, dp.Description
FROM [dbo].[CALLS] calls LEFT JOIN [dbo].[DIALPLAN] dp ON dp.Prefixe = LEFT(SUBSTRING(calls.OutTel,3,LEN(calls.OutTel)),LEN(dp.Prefixe))
```

Is there any other way to have the same result in less time ?

EDIT 1:
This is the execution plan for solution 1 :

[image]

This is the execution plan for solution 2 :

[image]

EDIT 2 :
Here's some sample data 
`CALLS` table `OutTel` field only for display purposes

```
OutTel
----------------
0033170448508
0033155373050
0021620383555
0016465699156
00390689971917
```

`DIALPLAN` table

```
IdDialPlan  Prefixe         Type     Country         Description
----------- --------------- -------- --------------- ------------------------------
471         1646            Fixed    United States   United States - New York
32284       331             Fixed    France          France - Paris City
32318       3317044         Fixed    France          France - Paris City
34658       216             Fixed    Tunisia         Tunisia
34659       21620           Mobile   Tunisia         Tunisia - Mobile - Tunisiana
35571       3906            Fixed    Italy           Italy - Rome
```

Thanks.

Comment: did you indexed the columns `Prefixe` in `DIALPLAN` and `OutTel` in `CALLS` ?

Comment: do you have an execution plan?

Comment: @Monah for `Prefixe` in `DIALPLAN` I do have a `NONCLUSTRED INDEX` but not for `Outtel` in `CALLS`

Comment: @RuslanTolkachev I edited the question.

Comment: Some *sample data* and *expected results* would probably help this question immensely.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to make structural changes because your indexes always going to be seek because of joins on functions and those sorts are your TOP operators. 
You could try to use max() instead of top 1 but you nave Description there, so it would not work. 
 
You can create a mapping table that would be populated through what ever populates your 2 tables (hopefully it is a stored procedure and not an Entity Framework) with a clustered index so it would presort your columns but it will slow down your inserts and updates. It could also solve your index scan operations.